Calculating the fractional Laplacian of a constant function
I have a question about calculating the Spectral fractional Laplacian of a constant.
Let us recall the definition of the Spectral fractional Laplacian for $0<s<1$:
$$
\left(-\Delta_{\text {Spec }}\right)^s \phi(x)=\sum_{k \geq 1} \lambda_k^s  \phi_k e_k(x), 
$$
where $\{ e_k, \lambda_k \}$ are the eigenfunctions and the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ with the homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition, and $\phi_k$ represents the projection of $\phi$ in the direction $e_k$. ($\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$).
In the case of non-constant functions, we take $\phi_k=\int_\Omega \phi(x) e_k(x) dx$.
How to deal with the case where $\phi$ is a constant? It may be a zero but I don't see it with this definition.
Thank you very much in advance.

Why wouldn’t it work for only for non constant functions? Just expand the constant function in the modes.

You are right, It works for non-constant functions. But I don't see why the fractional Laplacian of a constant is zero.

In general, it is not zero for a constant function. You just need to expand the constant function in the eigenbasis.
Take for example $\Omega=(0,1)$. Then, you can take the orthogonal basis for $n\in\mathbb N^*$:
$$
\lambda_n=(\pi n)^2\\
e_n=\sin(\pi nx)
$$
You can then expand the constant function:
$$
1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac4{\sqrt{\lambda_{2k+1}}}e_{2k+1}(x)
$$
and compute the action of the fractional Laplacian:
$$
(-\Delta)^s1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty4\lambda_{2k+1}^{s-1/2}e_{2k+1}(x)
$$
You can even compute the function for specific values like $s=0,1/2,1$. For general $s$ you can relate it to the polylogarithm on the unit circle.
Hope this helps.
